# Mounting heat source onto heat pipes

Tags: heat-transfer

I want to mount a heat source onto several heat pipes. The heat will be forwarded to coolers (four heat pipes, 200 mm) which are able to distribute up to 120 W without increasing the temperature of the device which should be cooled. The device itself will generate up to 100 W heat. Now I was wondering what would happen to the mounting point: Will the mounting point resp. the clamp used for fixing the heat source on the heat pipes also heat up? If yes, how much?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are asking. A drawing would help a lot. Also, the abbreviation "resp." seems confusing.

Comment: I am using "resp." for "respective". In this case I will clamp the heated device onto the heat pipes, therefore I use both words as synonyme.

Comment: Why would the clamp not heat up? It is touching something that is warmer than it is. The fact that it is touching a "heat pipe" doesn't make it magic.

Comment: @hazzey: The question is how much it would heat up, if the heat pipe is attached to something which has always room temperature.

Comment: @arc_lupus As hazzey pointed out, the question is very unclear at the moment.  Can you add a drawing?

Comment: @arc_lupus Add a drawing, or your question will be closed. They want to really help, but they really don't understand. I also don't. If you can't add a drawing, I will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, how much the clamp heats up is determined by a great number of factors, chiefly (off the top of my head):

- The properties of the pipe (material properties: density, material
  type, size of contact area etc)
- How the clamp interfaces with the pipe (e.g. metal on metal, thermal
  interface material between clamp and pipe, an insulator between clamp
  and pipe).
- The properties of the clamp (material properties, initial temperature etc)

Regards the resp. abbeviation I think you're using it incorrectly. I'd say "Will the mounting point w.r.t. the clamp....." where w.r.t. means with respect to.